# JSON data missing while sending to server

Tags: java, android, json, node.js

When I parse an JSON object, it gets parsed easily and in the correct format. But as soon as I send the same thing to the server side, values go missing.

```
    JSONArray check0 = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray check1 = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray check2 = new JSONArray();

    check0.put(v11);
    check0.put(v12);
    check0.put(v13);

    check1.put(c11);
    check1.put(c12);
    check1.put(c13);

    check4.put(t11);
    check4.put(t12);
    check4.put(t13);


    draft.put("check2",id11);
    draft.put("check3",t11);

    draft.put("check0",check0);
    draft.put("check1",check1);
    draft.put("check4",check4);
```

where v11,v12.......t12,t13 are string variables.

My code for sending data:

```
URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/initial");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0");
connection.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "en-US,en;0.5");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream dStream = new 
DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
System.out.println(draft.toString());
dStream.writeBytes(draft.toString());
```

System.out:

```
{"Check1":["5","4","4"],"Check0":["6","44","4"],"Check2":"17082017123406","Check4":"1228123682","Check3":["4","4","4"]}
```

Code to receive the post request:

```
app.post('/initial', function(req, res){

console.log("POST received: "+ JSON.stringify(req.body));

res.end("cool");
});
```

Console output
POST received:

`{"{\"Check1\":":{"\"5\",\"4\",\"4\"":{"\"6\",\"44\",\"4\"":{"\"4\",\"4\",\"4\"":""}}}}`

Comment: please share some of your code so someone can judge the error.

Comment: I have updated the code,please help me out.

Comment: please share the code where you are creating the request json.

Comment: Please, Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

try using the following

```
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

Example

```
private JSONObject uploadToServer() throws IOException, JSONException {
        String query = "https://example.com";
        String json = "{\"key\":1}";

        URL url = new URL(query);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        os.close();

        // read the response
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        String result = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);


        in.close();
        conn.disconnect();

        return jsonObject;
}
```